Parsing named command-line arguments on C (Windows)
I'm currently developing a tool on Windows with Visual Studio with C, however I've noticed that I cannot import libraries such as unistd.h into my source file for command-line argument parsing.
Currently, I'm working with the strcmp to check for command-line arguments and associate a flag with a value.
// Get supplied command-line arguments
SQLCHAR* server = NULL;
SQLCHAR* database = NULL;
SQLCHAR* username = NULL;
SQLCHAR* password = NULL;
SQLCHAR* query = NULL;

for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0) {
        server = argv[i + 1];
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0) {
        database = argv[i + 1];
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-u") == 0) {
        username = argv[i + 1];
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0) {
        password = argv[i + 1];
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-q") == 0) {
        query = argv[i + 1];
    }
}

Is there a better way of doing this on Windows?
Thank you.

You can use CommandLineToArgvW for example, if want "classic" style command line format. Or design by self own format and process it by self

"Is there a better way" If you stick with Unix-style options and process yourself, you should at least fix your attempt in 2 places: A) i < argc that loop condition is wrong as you access argv[i + 1]. B): You do not skip the arguments of previously found options.

Hint: If the first char is '-', and the third char is '\0', then you've got '-', '?', '\0'. If so, then simply use switch( argv[i][1] ) to switch on whatever the ? character is (and handle default: for unrecognised entry.) It's exactly the same, but a lot less to read/maintain. Using library functions is a great beginning. But, there's no reason to write code that has limited portability (if you want C code to be portable.)

unistd.h is not part of the Windows API (it is not part of the C Standard, so you can not blame Windows), but you can get getopt() and getopt_long() (GNU extension) to compile with MinGW on Windows to parse them the way you do in UNIX-like operating systems.
If you can't do that, you can simply get a copy of the getopt()'s source and use it in your code (it is distributed under GNU General Public License albeit).
This SO answer also shows a sample implementation: getopt().
Microsoft also provides an implementation inside the open source Iotivity software framework (it is distributed under Apache 2.0 license albeit).
